# How do I connect my 5.1 sound bar with my desktop via HDMI?

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a nvidea card with 3DP and one HDMI port, in my mother board I have 1DP and 1HDMI.
Neither my motherboard nor my card has any optical out.
I want to connect my 5.1 sound system with my PC via HDMI.
None of my monitors have an HDMI out.
My sound system also do not have HDMI out. It has stereo, optical and HDMI in and bluetooth.

Is there anyway I can have 5.1 sound from my sound system from my desktop?

Comment: yes you should be able to connect the HDMI from the video card to the soundbar. you will have to configure your system to use the soundbar as its default audio output device, and configure it for 5.1, but should work, if I'm understanding you correctly. you couldn't use HDMI outputs from the monitors anyway unless they were ARC/eARC ports anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a displayport to hdmi adapter cable or dongle...  I haven't done this but I think odds are good that you could use one hdmi out for Audio and another for Video.  I know the dongle will do video and audio on a single monitor so it should be able to do just one or the other.  The only trick is choosing the sound output source once its all hooked up. Does your monitor have Displayport?  If so you could just get a displayport cable and use the hdmi for audio.  Audio source will say nvidia